# Parametrized custom stream manipulators - why overload "operator<<"?

Tags: c++, iostream, manipulators

I am trying to implement a parametrized stream manipulator for a certain set of data. I do it the simple way as recommended:

```
class print_my_data
{
private:
    . . .

public:
    print_my_data(. . .) { . . . }

    ostream& operator()(std::ostream& out)
    {
        return out << . . . << endl;
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, print_my_data md) // <=== MY QUESTION BELOW IS ABOUT THIS
{
    return md(out);
}
```

Usage:

```
clog << print_my_data(. . .) << endl;
```

This works fine; but I really don't understand why it doesn't work unless I define `operator<<`! Why won't it call the same overloaded function as it does for `endl`?? (i.e. as an object that can be applied to the stream through `operator()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) you're looking for is only defined for function pointers.

> ```
> basic_ostream& operator<<(
>    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
> ```

Your `print_my_data` class is a callable object (a *functor*, in C++ terms). But it is not a function pointer. On the other hand, [`endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a function, and hence has a function pointer (in fact, it's one of the few functions in the C++ standard library which *do* have an address)

A not-unreasonable argument could be made that the overload should look like

> ```
> basic_ostream& operator<<(
>    std::function<std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&)> func);
> ```

But alas, `std::function` wasn't around when the I/O manipulation operators were written. Neither were concepts, for that matter. And using SFINAE to declare

> ```
> template <typename F>
> basic_ostream& operator<<(
>    F func);
> ```

would have just opened an entire Pandora's box worth of messy details that the standards committee didn't want to deal with.

Comment: Anyway, neither of function pointer nor `print_my_data` is a `std::function`, and so that overload would not be selected neither.